# Qué este código tenga limite de 3 intentos para acertar el número

Tags: javascript

Este es el código, ocupo ayuda para que solo permita dar 3 intentos para adivinar el número, si el usuario supera los 3 intentos el programa se cierra, ya he intentado pero no lo logro, estoy trabajando con el bloc de notas por ahora, soy nuevo en esto graciasssss.

```
<html>
<body>
<title>Vamos a contar</title>
<script>
  
  var azar = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 );

  //adivinarsinintentoswhile();
  adivinarsinintentosdowhile();

function adivinarsinintentoswhile(){

  var acierto = false ;

while (acierto == false){

  var n1 = prompt("Adivina un numero del 0 al 5");

if (n1==azar) {

  acierto=true;
  document.write("Adivinaste, el número era " + azar);

 }

else {

  alert("Vuelve a intentar");

    }
  } 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías de crear una nueva variable que cuente los errores que el usuario cometió hasta el momento, y que la condición del while también incluya que esta nueva variable sea menor que 3.

Quedaría de esta forma:

```
    function adivinarsinintentoswhile(){
    
    var acierto = false ;
    var contadorErrores = 0;
    
    while (acierto == false && contadorErrores <3){ //El while solo se ejecutara si el usuario no acertó y aún no supera los 3 errores
    
          var n1 = prompt("Adivina un numero del 0 al 5");
        
        if (n1==azar) {
            acierto=true;
            document.write("Adivinaste, el número era " + azar);
         } else {
            contadorErrores++; //Si se equivoca, el contador de errores sube
            alert("Vuelve a intentar");
        }
        
        }
        
          if (contadorErrores === 3) window.close(); //El programa se cierra si el contador de errores llega a 3
   }
```